# How to append variables into another variable outside for loop?

Tags: javascript

I will explain the main objective of my question.
I need to build a variable with this specific data structure:

**date,value(line break)**

```
2019-05-14 12:00:00,7.8
2019-05-15 00:00:00,14.5
2019-05-17 05:00:00,1
2019-05-19 20:00:00,2.3
2019-05-28 08:00:00,33.4
2019-05-28 10:00:00,18.8
2019-05-28 12:00:00,11.5
```

The purpose of this is to pass this variable with this exact structure to HighCharts as data input to create a Chart.

In order to retrieve and generate this data, I made a foor loop that reads a nested JSON array called **"datos"** (which contains an array with those values).
Below in the code you can see the values of **"fecha"**(date) and **"valor"**(value) variables.

```
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) { 
    var v = findPropPath(datos[i], 'v' );
    var object = datos[i], 
        path = v, 
        getValue = (o, p) => p.split('.').reduce((r, k) => r[k], o);

    var fecha = datos[i].data.time.s;   // fecha = "2019-05-14 12:00:00"
    var valor = getValue(object, path); // valor = "3.2"

    var comma = ",";
    var enter = "\n\r";
    var datosF = fecha.concat(comma, valor, enter);

    console.log(datosF);
};
```

As you can see, I tried to concatenate everything in a new variable called **datosF**.
Right now I'm stuck at this point because I don't know how to concatenate each line into a new variable that will contain all the lines inside as shown in the output example above.

At the moment, the **console.log(datosF)** gives the following:

[image: Console output]

I'm not even sure if my approach for the solution is valid, I'm a noob yet and can't find the proper solution yet.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post `datos`? It's hard to guess what it contains and might make answers irrelevant or inaccurate.

Comment: He says and shows that the code up to this point works. So there is no need to worry about all that (although the code looks very dodgy)

Comment: Thank you **ggorlen** & **Mister Jojo** for asking about it, as **Avin Kavish** said, the code posted so far works perfect. Thankfully Avin gave me the answer I was looking for (and it was sooooo simple once I saw it lol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to write this. With the least modification,

```
var datosF = '' 
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) { 
    var v = findPropPath(datos[i], 'v' );
    var object = datos[i], 
        path = v, 
        getValue = (o, p) => p.split('.').reduce((r, k) => r[k], o);

    var fecha = datos[i].data.time.s;   // fecha = "2019-05-14 12:00:00"
    var valor = getValue(object, path); // valor = "3.2"

    var comma = ",";
    var enter = "\n\r";
    datosF = datosF.concat(fetcha, comma, valor, enter);

};

    console.log(datosF);
```

You have to save the result from each iteration into a variable from the outer scope.

There are a few bad practices going on here though. Such as creating a function in each iteration of the loop. Posting the original data will lead to the most concise solution.

Comment: Avin, you are the best! This is the answer I was looking for, and actually once I see it, it was soooo simple haha, but with my actual knowledge I wasn't able to get that far. Thank you for teaching me something new!